# Issue with saving a user's dark mode preference

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to use localStorage to save the dark mode preference on my website. The issue I am running into is when you switch to dark mode and hit refresh, it stays in dark mode. However, if you switch to dark mode, then back to light mode, and hit refresh, it loads dark mode.

I am stuck so far and haven't been able to find any helpful resources on this yet.

Here is my fiddle along with my js script below.

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8a0do7pg/)

```
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
   $('ul').click(function(){
    $('ul').toggleClass('active')
    let darkThemeEnabled = $('section').toggleClass('dark');
    localStorage.setItem('dark-theme-enabled', darkThemeEnabled);
   })
  })

    if (localStorage.getItem('dark-theme-enabled')) {
        $('section').toggleClass('dark');
      $('ul').toggleClass('active') 
    }
 </script>
```

Comment: You could create a cookie or use localStorage to save their prefences in a variable. Have you tried anything yourself?

Comment: ...or depending on backend store a user profile server-side. This is too broad as is. Please edit to be more specific.

Comment: cookies, localstorage, or backend....

Comment: @LucaKiebel yes I have tried using localStorage. I revised my question to be more specific and have updated it a bit as my issue is more defined now.

Comment: @JaredSmith sorry - I have updated the question to be more specific.

Comment: From review to reopen. Check what kind of value `.toggleClass`  returns. Couldn't find any mention of a return value in jQuery docs, but a quick test showed it an DOM element object for how I tested it..

Answer (score 1):

You can save it and get it by using `localStorage`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var darkMode = localStorage.getItem('dark') || false;
  $('ul').click(function() {
    $('ul').toggleClass('active')
    $('section').toggleClass('dark');
    darkMode = !darkMode;
    localStorage.setItem("dark", darkMode);
  });
});
```

And in answer to your second question - no, you need to include the scripts on every page you want this to happen.